# Disabling subcharts in custom helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, elastic-stack, kubernetes-helm, kubeconfig

I've created a custom helm chart with `elastic-stack` as a subchart with following configurations.

```
# requirements.yaml
dependencies:
  - name: elastic-stack
    version: 1.5.0
    repository: '@stable'
```

```
# values.yaml
elastic-stack:
  kibana:
    # at this level enabled is not recognized (does not work)
    # enabled: true

    # configs like env, only work at this level
    env:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://foo-elasticsearch-client.default.svc.cluster.local:9200
    service:
      externalPort: 80

# enabled only works at root level
elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
kibana:
  enabled: true
logstash:
  enabled: false
```

What i don't get is why i have to define the `enabled` tags outside the `elasatic-stack:` and all other configurations inside?

Is this a normal helm behavior or some misconfiguration in elastic-stack chart?

Answer (score 5):

[Helm conditions](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-requirements-yaml) are evaluated in the top parent's values:

> Condition - The condition field holds one or more YAML paths
>   (delimited by commas). If this path exists in the top parent’s values
>   and resolves to a boolean value, the chart will be enabled or disabled
>   based on that boolean value

Take a look at the conditions in [requirements.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/dbfe5e6b55f67ddb513e41a4417160a1ab8c7b6d/stable/elastic-stack/requirements.yaml) from stable/elastic-stack:

```
- name: elasticsearch
  version: ^1.17.0
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  condition: elasticsearch.enabled
- name: kibana
  version: ^1.1.0
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  condition: kibana.enabled
- name: logstash
  version: ^1.2.1
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  condition: logstash.enabled
```

The conditions paths are `elasticsearch.enabled`, `kibana.enabled` and `logstash.enabled`, so you need to use them in your parent chart values.

Answer (score 1):

Those properties in parent values.yaml serve as switch for the subcharts.

You are suppose to use `condition` in your requirements.yaml to control the installation or execution of your dependent subcharts. If not provided then helm simply proceeds to deploy the subchart without and problem.

And also, those values are in parent's values.yaml because they are being used in the parent chart itself and moreover cannot be used inside the subchart unless provided as global or within the subchart's name property key (which is in your case elastic-stack).